# Generation of migration files from ezplatform with kaliop

Tags: migration, ezpublish, ezplatform

Using ezplatform with `"kaliop/ezmigrationbundle": "^3.0"`.

I read and re-read the manual but cannot see anything about auto-generating yml files from exsiting content types; does anyone have any experience with this and happen to know if/where the docs might live?

We have a list of content types that were created in the backend via the gui and now we need to create migration files for them for better development with the dev team.

---

Update: This is available on v4+  https://github.com/kaliop-uk/ezmigrationbundle/issues/34#issuecomment-317524072#issuecomment-317524072

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is available on v4+ and answers the question

https://github.com/kaliop-uk/ezmigrationbundle/issues/34#issuecomment-317524072#issuecomment-317524072

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is not how it works!

the bundle generate just an empty yaml file for you and you should fill up the content types (or any other Backend Changes you want) yourself in that yaml file and then take it and apply to your stage or Live Environment.

so unlike Symfony DoctorineMigrationBunlde, this bundle does not read the difference and produce stuff itself.

Comment: Yup it looks that way, total shame though as building a site from scratch with a designer is way easier to us the admin to put together the content types.

Comment: if someone has not actively worked on Production website, you just can take a dump from your local DB and take it to Live! That was the traditional approach we had to do.

Comment: https://github.com/kaliop-uk/ezmigrationbundle/issues/34#issuecomment-317524072#issuecomment-317524072